# Is there an event for IOS that would allow me to listen for login?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native

Is there an event emitted that could be listened for from the user logging in to the iPhone(inputting password or Fingerprint)? Preferably an answer that allowed me to use JavaScript but open to anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically not allowed on iOS. There are ways of doing it through private Apple APIs but your app may get rejected from the app store